# Brace in the same column

Tags: equations, braces

I have a problem with set of equations. 
To wit: I would like to set a braces in the same column, 
but I have no idea how to meki it. 
Belowe I enclose a code.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

$\left.
\begin{array}{ll} 
1) & \varphi \rightarrow \varphi \\
2) & (\varphi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow ((\psi \rightarrow \chi\rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow \chi)) \\
3) & \varphi \wedge \psi \rightarrow \varphi \ \text{oraz} \  \varphi \wedge \psi \rightarrow \psi \\
\end{array}
\right \} $ 
$
\begin{tabular}{|C{4cm}|}  \hline
Równoważność \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
$


$ \left.
\begin{array}{ll}
4) & (\varphi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow ((\varphi \rightarrow \chi) \rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow \psi \wedge \chi) \\
5) & \varphi \rightarrow \varphi \vee \psi  \ \text{oraz} \ \psi \rightarrow \varphi \vee \psi \\
6) & (\varphi \rightarrow \chi) \rightarrow ((\psi \rightarrow \chi) \rightarrow (\varphi \vee \psi \rightarrow \chi) \\
7) & \text{dystrybutywność}  
\end{array}
\right \} $
$
\begin{tabular}{|C{4cm}|}  \hline
Krata \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
$

$ \left.
\begin{array}{ll}
8) & \varphi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \varphi) \\
9) & \neg \varphi \rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow \psi)
\end{array}
\right \} $
$
\begin{tabular}{|C{4cm}|}  \hline
Jedynka i zero \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
$

$ \left.
\begin{array}{ll}
10) & \neg(\varphi \wedge \neg \varphi) \\
11) & \varphi \vee \neg \varphi
\end{array}
\right \} $
$
\begin{tabular}{|C{4cm}|}  \hline
Dopełnienie \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
$
```

I'm going to get final efect looks like [image]

I've got solution but my preambul looks like

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{report} 
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, blkarray}
```

\newcommand\eqcomment[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYlPg.png){\fbox{\makebox[4cm]{#1}}}

and now when I compile my code the program shows error

! Undefined control sequence.
 \adl@connect
l.477 1 & 1 & 1 \ \hline
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple solution with `blkarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array, blkarray}
\newcommand\eqcomment[1]{\fbox{\makebox[4cm]{#1}}}

\begin{document}


\[ \setlength\BAextrarowheight{3pt}
  \hspace*{-5cm}
  \begin{blockarray}{l}
    \begin{block}{\BAenum!{)\hskip\labelsep} l\Right{\}\enspace}{\eqcomment{Równoważność }}}
      \varphi  \rightarrow \varphi \\
      (\varphi  \rightarrow \psi )  \rightarrow ((\psi  \rightarrow \chi \rightarrow (\varphi  \rightarrow \chi )) \\
      \varphi  \wedge  \psi  \rightarrow \varphi \ \text{oraz} \ \varphi  \wedge  \psi  \rightarrow \psi \\%
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{\BAenum!{)\hskip\labelsep} l\Right{\}\enspace}{\eqcomment{Krata}}}
      (\varphi  \rightarrow \psi )  \rightarrow ((\varphi  \rightarrow \chi )  \rightarrow (\varphi  \rightarrow \psi  \wedge  \chi ) \\
      \varphi  \rightarrow \varphi  \vee \psi \ \text{oraz} \ \psi  \rightarrow \varphi  \vee \psi \\
      (\varphi  \rightarrow \chi )  \rightarrow ((\psi  \rightarrow \chi )  \rightarrow (\varphi  \vee \psi  \rightarrow \chi ) \\
      \text{dystrybutywność}\\
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{\BAenum!{)\hskip\labelsep} l\Right{\}\enspace}{\eqcomment{Jedynka i zero}}}
      \varphi  \rightarrow (\psi  \rightarrow \varphi ) \\
      \neg \varphi  \rightarrow (\varphi  \rightarrow \psi ) \\
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{\BAenum!{)\hskip\labelsep} l\Right{\}\enspace}{\eqcomment{Dopełnienie}}}
      \neg(\varphi  \wedge  \neg \varphi ) \\
      \varphi  \vee \neg \varphi \\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}%
\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but my preabule looks like

Comment: Your preamble has inconsistencies: you loaded  `3` fonts (maybe 4, as I don't know if `polski` loads fonts): `lmodern`, `pxfonts` and `txfonts`, of which the last two are outdated, and conflict with `amsmath`. If you want Times-like fonts, remove `lmodern` and `pxfonts`, and replace `txfonts` with  `\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}`. If you want Palatino-like, replace `pxfonts` with `\usepackage{newpxtext, newpxmath}` and remove the other two.

Comment: It works, but I have next problem now. everywhere I used a array Tex shows a error. I think it causes \hline because when I deleted it, succes compile.

Comment: Could you provide a link with a minimal (fully compilable) example? I can't imagine why  `blkarray` would interfere with  `array` or `\hline`.

Comment: I don'k konw why it works. 
I removed \usepackage{array, blkarray}
and add \usepackage{blkarray}.
Now, everithink is complied succesfull

Comment: Fine. To be true, I don't know why I loaded array. Initially, I didn't, and there was a problem I didn't understand, so I added array, just to see, and it worked! LaTeX can be mysterious at times…

Comment: You save my thesis :) So, thank you very much.